# Email attachment for document files using rails action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am using Rails action mailer. I need to send a email with document(doc, docx, txt) as attachment. When I am attaching .txt files, the content in that txt file are viewing properly. But when I am trying to attach .doc or docx files, the content in that files are not displaying(it is converting into encoding format) Why is that happening. Is there any way to attach document files in email using rails action mailer.

```
def send_email(email, file)
  @email = email
  attachments['document.docx'] = File.read(file.path)
  mail(from: @email, to: "aa@gmail.com", subject: "Document attachment")
end
```

[original document attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPXi2.png)

[document received in email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSfWp.png)

Please guide me, if I am going wrong in some place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try setting the mimetype to zip i.e.
`attachments['document.docx'] = { mime_type: 'application/zip', content: File.read(file.path) }`

Comment: Tried with mime_type also not worked :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file in binary mode (see [binary file mode](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) & [`:mode` option](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Encoding):

```rb
attachments['document.docx'] = File.read(file.path, mode: 'rb')
```

In my case, Rails was adding a carriage return (aka "CR", or "\r") to every line in a CSV file that ended with either a "\n" (newline) or "\r".